# C++ How to copy the allocator object in a container class copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, allocator

I'm implementing a ring buffer container class:

```
template <class T, class A = std::allocator<T>>
class ring {
private:
    size_type cap_;  // the capacity of the array
    alloc_type alloc_;  // the allocator
    pointer array_;
    ...  
public:
    ring(size_type n, const alloc_type &a = alloc_type()) : cap_{n}, alloc_{a}, array_{alloc_.allocate((size_t)cap_)}, ... {
       memset(array_, 0, (size_t)cap_ * sizeof(T));
    }
    ...
};
```

(I have not shown the typedefs here, but they're obvious.)

I'm not sure how to write the (deep) copy constructor so that it handles the allocator correctly, but I imagine that the copy must have its own allocator (of the same type), and then I'd loop through the original allocated array and copy element by element.

Would it be something like this?:

```
ring(const self_type& r) : cap_{r.cap_}, ... {
    alloc_ = ???  // not sure what to do here
    array_ = alloc_.allocate((size_t)cap_);
    for (size_type i{}; i < r.size(); ++i) {   
        alloc_.construct(array_[i], r.array_[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would expect the allocator to be initialized in the initialization section of the constructor, effectively invoking the allocator's copy constructor. It is the allocator's responsibility to implement its copy constructor properly.

Comment: It's subtle. See [`AllocatorAwareContainer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer), note the use of [`std::allocator_traits::select_on_container_copy_construction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ring(const self_type& r)
  : alloc_(std::allocator_traits<alloc_type>::
        select_on_container_copy_construction(r.alloc_)) {
}
```

See also: [AllocatorAwareContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer)

Comment: Many thanks. After that, I copy the elements of the array as I have indicated?